# Can we protect this question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, question-protection

The question, [Why are my carrots and potatoes popping out of the ground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85623/why-are-my-carrots-and-potatoes-popping-out-of-the-ground), seems to be attracting a lot of anecdotal/duplicate answers from new users as of late, most of which would serve their purpose as comments, or would be better off not being said.

Is this a good candidate for protection?

Comment: For future reference, this sort of request is generally better served by a flag than a meta post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the page from answers that didn't talk about the nether and community did the rest for me.